# How do I unhide a class from Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Stupid thing I need help with; I accidentally hid the `java.io.File` class from the IDE

As in, it doesn't show up in the intellisense/autocomplete when I type. I can still use the class though, it just doesn't show up anymore.

It doesn't show up in the list of excluded classes in `Settings -> Project Settings -> Compiler -> Excludes`

Any help as to how I bring it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import and check the Exclude section.

I simulated your accidental File hiding, and it appeared there. I removed it, et voila...

[image: Hidden File class]